# iCheck checkbox is not working in flutter Android webviews

Tags: icheck, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

iCheck is not working in flutter Android webviews. I used both Flutter WebView and Inappwebview. I can see checkbox color is changed. But is not giving any response when clicking. Same for radio buttons. But it is working without any issues in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved after adding user agent in javascript source code.